# how to get the results from table A where the data in table B are only true

Tags: postgresql

how to get records from two tables where all for example statuses are  true in the second table.

```
Table A                    Table B
id   name           id   idA  status
9    'name1'        20   9    true
                    21   9    false
7    'name2'        22   7    true
                    23   7    true
                    24   7    true
6    'name3'        30   6    false
                    31   6    true
                    32   6    false
output
result: 
table A             tableB
7    'name2'        22   7    true
                    23   7    true
                    24   7    true
```

I would like to get the results from table A where the data in table B are only true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in two ways:

Having "only true" means that there should not be any status with false in table b:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where not exists (select *
                  from table_b b
                  where b.ida = a.id
                  and not status)
```

Alternatively one can use the aggregate function `bool_and()` to find those rows that have only true values for the status column:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where exists (select b.ida
              from table_b b
              where b.ida = a.id
              group by b.ida
              having bool_and(status))
```

Comment: thx, i chose the your first solution with not exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation function `bool_and` for this purpose. If it returns true for a given `idA`, the corresponding record in `tableA` must be returned.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE id IN (SELECT idA from tableB GROUP BY idA HAVING bool_and(status))
```

The magic is in the `HAVING bool_and(status)` which means "keep the idA for which `true` (implicit) is returned after aggregation".

Answer (score 0):

For your question I will use `NOT EXISTS` operator like this :

```
   select ta.id, ta.name, tb.id, tb.idA, status
    from tableA ta
    LEFT JOIN tableB tb On ta.id = tb.idA
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select idA
    from tableB tbb
    where status = 'false' and tbb.idA = ta.id);
```

it will not take any id that has `false` at least once

Comment: thx, its good for me, i used this for status=false to get only true and status=true for only false.